# Windows update error code 8000FFFF

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-7, wsus, windows-update

We are using WSUS for updates. Last week I pushed out 2019-01 Monthly Security roll up for servers and desktops. Almost 1/3 systems had update failure with the same error code 8000FFFF, "Windows update encountered an unknow error", it happened on servers and desktops.

I did a lot of researches and there is nothing useful to fix this issue.

We never had any issue with WSUS pushing our updates

Anyone had the similar issue before? below part of CBS.log

`2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller initialization.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    Loaded Servicing Stack v6.1.7601.17592 with Core: C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17592_none_672ce6c3de2cb17f\cbscore.dll
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CSI    00000001@2019/3/1:05:40:35.675 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7feef4cf0ad @0x7feef789849 @0x7feef7534e3 @0xffbfe97c @0xffbfd799 @0xffbfdb2f)
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    Could not load SrClient DLL from path: SrClient.dll.  Continuing without system restore points.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CSI    00000002@2019/3/1:05:40:35.675 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7feef4cf0ad @0x7feef7d6816 @0x7feef7a2aac @0x7feef7535b9 @0xffbfe97c @0xffbfd799)
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CSI    00000003@2019/3/1:05:40:35.675 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7feef4cf0ad @0x7fef5048738 @0x7fef5048866 @0xffbfe474 @0xffbfd7de @0xffbfdb2f)
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller initialization.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    Starting the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    TrustedInstaller service starts successfully.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    SQM: Initializing online with Windows opt-in: False
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    SQM: Cleaning up report files older than 10 days.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    SQM: Requesting upload of all unsent reports.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    SQM: Failed to start upload with file pattern: C:\Windows\servicing\sqm\*_std.sqm, flags: 0x2 [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    SQM: Failed to start standard sample upload. [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    SQM: Queued 0 file(s) for upload with pattern: C:\Windows\servicing\sqm\*_all.sqm, flags: 0x6
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    SQM: Warning: Failed to upload all unsent reports. [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    No startup processing required, TrustedInstaller service was not set as autostart, or else a reboot is still pending.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    NonStart: Checking to ensure startup processing was not required.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CSI    00000004 IAdvancedInstallerAwareStore_ResolvePendingTransactions (call 1) (flags = 00000004, progress = NULL, phase = 0, pdwDisposition = @0xc3fe80
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CSI    00000005 Creating NT transaction (seq 1), objectname [6]"(null)"
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CSI    00000006 Created NT transaction (seq 1) result 0x00000000, handle @0x1f8
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CSI    00000007@2019/3/1:05:40:35.706 CSI perf trace:
CSIPERF:TXCOMMIT;11277
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    NonStart: Success, startup processing not required as expected.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    Startup processing thread terminated normally
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CSI    00000008 CSI Store 3051984 (0x00000000002e91d0) initialized
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1262411695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-ActiveX~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, ApplicableState: 80, CurrentState:112
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1262567695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-Aux-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, ApplicableState: 80, CurrentState:64
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1262723695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:35, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: WUClient-SelfUpdate-Core-TopLevel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7.6.7600.320, ApplicableState: 80, CurrentState:112
2019-03-01 00:40:37, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1277075695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:37, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:37, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1277075696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:37, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:37, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1279259695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1295483695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1295483696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1295483697 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1295639695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1295639696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1295639697 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1295639698 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1295639699 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1297979695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB3035126~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:32
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1297979696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB2862335~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 80, CurrentState:112
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1297979697 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4486474~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~11.2.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1298291695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4480965~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~11.2.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1298603695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4483187~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~11.2.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1298915695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4470199~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~11.2.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1299227695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4466536~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~11.2.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1299383695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4462949~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~11.2.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1299695695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4457426~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~11.2.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1300007695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4343205~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~11.2.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1300319695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4339093~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~11.2.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1300631695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4230450~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~11.2.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1300787695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB2656356~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1, ApplicableState: 80, CurrentState:112
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1301099695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:39, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1301567695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:40, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7601.24356.1.4, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:40, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1305779695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:40, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1306247695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:40, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7601.24334.1.6, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:40, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1310303695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:40, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1310927695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:40, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7601.24312.1.5, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:40, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1315139695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:40, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1315451695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7601.24289.1.11, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1319663695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1320911695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~7601.24263.1.4, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:112
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325123695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB2862330~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:32
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325123696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325123697 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325123698 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4019990~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325279695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4483458~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325279696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:41, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4019990~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325435695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4480063~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325435696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4019990~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325435697 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4470641~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325591695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4019990~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325591696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4457044~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325747695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4019990~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325903695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4344152~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325903696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4019990~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1325903697 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4338423~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1326059695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4019990~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1326059696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4095874~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1326215695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4019990~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1326215696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4054998~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1326683695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4040980~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1326683696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4019990~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1326683697 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4014504~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:112
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1326839695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB4014565~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1326839696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB3210131~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1326995695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB3127220~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:112
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1327151695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB2690533~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:112
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1327307695 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Microsoft-Hyper-V-Integration-Services-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.17388, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:0
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1327307696 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Read out cached package applicability for package: Package_for_KB3010788~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1, ApplicableState: 112, CurrentState:112
2019-03-01 00:40:42, Info                  CBS    Session: 30724081_1327307697 initialized by client WindowsUpdateAgent.`

Comment: Just wondering... do you have a support contract with Microsoft? If so, you can create a support ticket with them.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't......

Comment: Did you try DISM? Can you share some log from CBS.log file, which captures this error code (relevant 10-20 lines up and down)!

Comment: uploaded part of log files

Comment: @RootLoop - Unfortunately, the log file snippet shared by you doesn't contain any significant hint of patch installation error! If you're comfortable, you may try uploading the file on any of the cloud service (Dropbox / Google Drive, etc.), and then share the link here...